# Redirecting to permalink URL with credentials

Tags: soundcloud

We have a special case, where we are uploading audio assets from our asset management system to Soundcloud. It works fine, but when redirecting the user I would like to do the authentication to a certain user on their behalf if they are not logged while doing the redirect. The workflow goes something like this:

1. User chooses an audio asset in DAM
2. User clicks the plugin that calls an API which handles the upload to Soundcloud
3. We redirect the user to permalink_url from the response

The problem is that we have two separate accounts. I would like to authenticate / login the user with certain credentials before the redirect. Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

yes that should be possible.

user grants access for your app, you store the tokens and may refresh it later or request new ones.

more here:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#connect

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#token

[oAuth 2.0 - Acting on behalf of the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512794/oauth-2-0-acting-on-behalf-of-the-user)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I was looking for. I want to redirect and login the user with the credentials I have. The app doing the API calls is already authorized.

Comment: you have the credentials for the user? where is the problem then?