# Impersonation using JWT

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am trying to implement JWT authorization based on this [article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/).
I also need to let specific users (admins) impersonate other users (clients).

I see two possibilities here:

- make admin requests using the admin token and add the impersonated client_id to each of the request;
- request a new token for the admin which will contain the username and roles of the CLIENT in its payload, so it will basically become a client token, but it will also have two extra fields: "impersonated=true" and "impersonator_admin_id=x".

I would prefer the second one as it would be easier to use the .net built-in authorization attribute with the clients roles.
But I'm not sure if this opens up security holes or if it can be actually implemented using .Net's OAuthAuthorizationServer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512794/oauth-2-0-acting-on-behalf-of-the-user

Answer (score 5):

From your links, first decide if the admin is impersonating an user or acting on behalf of. Note that **on-behalf-of != impersonation**

- **A acts on behalf of B** when A maintain its own identity and is given all rights from B
- **A impersonates B** when for all intents and purposes A is B

In [JWT RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-10.1) is not defined any specific claim for this purpose. In this [draft](http://self-issued.info/docs/on-behalf-of.html) the author proposes to include an on-behalf-of  claim `obo`

```
{"obo": {
    "prn":"mailto:joe@example.com",
    "ctx":["urn:adatum.com:calendar"]
}}
```

- `prn` identifies the principal for whom the bearer of the JWT is acting on behalf of.
- `ctx`  stablish permission contexts in which the bearer is allowed to act on behalf of the principal. This claim should by mandatory to restrict the contexts in which the delegated rights are to be exercised

Note that the `obo` claims are not included in [IANA's JSON Web Token Claims](http://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml), so they should be taken as a recommendation. There is a similar claim `azp` in OpenID but it is not clear how to apply it

- `azp` : Authorized party - the party to which the ID Token was issued

Answering your question, in the first case I think you are talking about acting on-behalf-of, so include the client_id and the security context. The second case  would be impersonation.

Answer (score 2):

Impersonation always comes with serious security implications as it allows "to become someone else".

For that reason, you would need to make sure to make this state as visible as possible by e.g. introducing intensive audit logging. Also (to distinguish between real logins and impersonation logins) you would want to be able to transfer information about this very special state within your JWT access tokens by e.g. adding additional impersonated and impersonator properties to the profile of the impersonated user (as you described in your second point).

In the end you would probably end up having an regular API endpoint excepting requests like this ...

```
POST https://YOUR_DOMAIN/users/{user_id}/impersonate
Content-Type:   'application/json'
Authorization:  'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}'
{
  impersonator_id: "IMPERSONATOR_ID"
}
```

... which would hand out specific impersonation tokens that would allow to use service "through the users eyes".

Comment: Not sure I'ld agree on the seriousness of security implications. If a service isn't prepared to handle `obo` yet it might default to a behavior where it processes an incoming request as with admin permissions. Yes, the logging/auditing might be misleading, but that's not all to be regarded here. On the other hand, `impersonation` will default to more restricted behavior (in case the impersonator is "admin" ofc.).